# How to import multiple components to main.js in svelte js?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

How could import an svelte component to a "target" different to body?

https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/master/src/main.js

I am trying the next:

```
import App from './App.svelte';
export default new App({ target: document.body.div});
```

How could I export multiple componentes to different targets?

```
import App1 from './App1.svelte';
import App2 from './App2.svelte';
export default new App1({ target: document.body.div1});   
export default new App2({ target: document.body.div2});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a "const" object instead "default" to html element #ids with document.getElementById() or body tag names with   document.getElementsByTagName()

```
import App1 from './App1.svelte';
import App2 from './App2.svelte';

export const app1 = new App1({ target: document.getElementById("div1") });   
export const app2 = new App2({ target: document.getElementById("div2") });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), like:

```
import App1 from './App1.svelte';
import App2 from './App2.svelte';

export const app1 = new App1({ target: document.getElementById("app1")});   
export const app2 = new App2({ target: document.getElementById("app2")});
```

And in Your html you need to have the following elements:

```
<div id="app1"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```

Comment: The exporting works but not the target.
How could targering a div of the document?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById` for getting the target element.